# How to use service inside of component function?

Tags: angular

So I'm using an inline input edit component as follows:

```
  <app-inline-input-edit 
    [label]="'Manufacturer'" 
    [required]="true" 
    [(ngModel)]="ctrlTypes.manufacturer"
    name="manufacturer"
    [changed]="onChange">
  </app-inline-input-edit>
```

inline-input-edit.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  ElementRef,
  ViewChild,
  Renderer,
  forwardRef,
  OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inline-input-edit',
  templateUrl: './inline-input-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inline-input-edit.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => InlineInputEditComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class InlineInputEditComponent implements OnInit {

  /** input control **/
  @ViewChild('inlineEditControl') inlineEditControl: ElementRef;
  /** The control label **/
  @Input() label = '';
  /** Type of input control **/
  @Input() type = 'text';
  /** Type of input control **/
  @Input() formField = 'text';
  /** Input value required **/
  @Input() required = false;
  /** Input control is disabled **/
  @Input() disabled = false;
  // Prefix the value
  @Input() prefix: any;
  // color of the confirm button
  @Input() confirmColor = 'primary';
  // color of the cancel button
  @Input() cancelColor = 'warn';

  @Input() changed: Function;

  /** private value of input **/
  private _value = '';
  /** value prior to editing **/
  private preValue = '';
  /** We are editing **/
  public editing = false;
  /** Callback when the value is changing **/
  public onChange: any = Function.prototype;
  /** Callback when the input is accessed **/
  public onTouched: any = Function.prototype;

  get value(): any {
    return this._value;
  }

  set value(v: any) {
    if (v !== this._value) {
      this._value = v;
      this.onChange(v);
    }
  }

  // ControlValueAccessor interface impl
  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value !== undefined) {
      this._value = value;
    }
  }

  // ControlValueAccessor interface impl
  public registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => {}): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  // ControlValueAccessor interface impl
  public registerOnTouched(fn: () => {}): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  cancel($event: Event) {
    this.value = this.preValue;
    this.editing = false;
  }

  confirm($event: Event) {
    this.editing = false;
    console.log('component', this);
    this.changed($event, this);
  }

  keypress($event) {
    if ($event.keyCode === 13) {
      this.confirm($event);
    }
  }

  // Start editing
  edit(value) {
    if (this.disabled) {
      return;
    }

    this.preValue = value;
    this.editing = true;
    // Set focus on the input element, but we need to give it one cycle so it is ready
    setTimeout(_ => this.inlineEditControl.nativeElement.focus());
  }


  constructor(element: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

ControllerTypesFormComponent.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { ControllerTypesService } from '../../services/controller-types.service';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { ControllerTypes } from '../../models/controller_types.model';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-controller-types-form',
  templateUrl: './controller-types-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./controller-types-form.component.css']
})
export class ControllerTypesFormComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(
    private controllerTypesService: ControllerTypesService,
    private dataService: DataService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id') || '';
  value = 'one';
  title = 'Add New';
  ctrlTypes: ControllerTypes;

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {}

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
   // handle response after api is ready
    this.controllerTypesService.createControllerType(ctrlTypes).subscribe(
      (data) => {},
      (error) => {}
    );

  }


  onChange(event, ctrl) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(ctrl);
    console.log(this.id); //undefined
    console.log(this.title); //undefined
    //controllerTypesService is undefined
this.controllerTypesService.createControllerType(toUpdate).subscribe(
          (data) => {},
          (error) => {}
        );

    }
```

In the above onChange() all members of the class are undefined except for function parameters (event, ctrl). However, onSubmit() works fine. I believe this is because onChange is the function that runs inside an inline-input-edit component. What is the best way to make the service available or 
is there a different approach to it that I'm missing.

Comment: Can you share more code about what you want to achieve? Maybe then We can help.

Comment: @PrateekGogiaI have updated the question with full code

Comment: So you are also getting title and id as undefined? Which should not be the case because you have defined explicitly over here and it should print. Can you check the code again? Because title should print for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `changed`-function to be an Output, rather that an input and emit when something changes.

```
@Input() changed: Function;

// ts
this.changed($event, this);
```

to

```
@Output() changed = new EventEmitter();

//ts
this.changed.emit($event);
```

and listen to this outpu in your ControllerTypesFormComponent

```
<app-inline-input-edit 
    [label]="'Manufacturer'" 
    [required]="true" 
    [(ngModel)]="ctrlTypes.manufacturer"
    name="manufacturer"
    (changed)="onChange($event)">
</app-inline-input-edit>

//ts
onChange(event) {
    this.controllerTypesService.createControllerType(toUpdate).subscribe(
      (data) => {},
      (error) => {}
    );
}
```

Comment: @user3840211 Glad I could help. Could you please mark the answer as solution?